# How to use cURL to FTPS upload to SecureTransport (hint: SITE AUTH and client certificates)

Tags: openssl, curl, ftps

I'm trying to connect to SecureTransport 4.5.1 via FTPS using curl compiled with gnutls.

You need to use `--ftp-alternative-to-user "SITE AUTH"` per http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2006-07/0068.html

Do you see anything wrong with my client certificates?

I try with

```
# mycert.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


# mykey.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And it says "530 No client certificate presented":

```
myuser@myserver ~ $ curl -v --ftp-ssl --cert mycert.crt  --key mykey.pem  --ftp-alternative-to-user "SITE AUTH" -T helloworld.txt ftp://ftp.example.com:9876/upload/
* About to connect() to ftp.example.com port 9876 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4... connected
* Connected to ftp.example.com (1.2.3.4) port 9876 (#0)
< 220 msn1 FTP server (SecureTransport 4.5.1) ready.
> AUTH SSL
< 334 SSLv23/TLSv1
* found 142 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
> USER anonymous
< 331 Password required for anonymous.
> PASS ftp@example.com
< 530 Login incorrect.
> SITE AUTH
< 530 No client certificate presented.
* Access denied: 530
* Closing connection #0

curl: (67) Access denied: 530
```

I also tried with a pk8 version...

```
# openssl pkcs8 -in mykey.pem -topk8 -nocrypt > mykey.pk8
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

...but got exactly the same result.

What's the trick to sending a client certificate to SecureTransport?

Answer (score 2):

The trick: **Don't use GnuTLS.** Make sure your cURL is compiled with OpenSSL, e.g.

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.19.4 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict http file https ftps 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I had previously recompiled cURL to use GnuTLS, but according to the mailing list [GnuTLS is not very well supported](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2011-11/0016.html).

Since I was on Gentoo, I got the default cURL back with

```
sudo USE="-gnutls" emerge curl
```

Finally, here's the command that works for me:

```
curl  --user NameInClientCert:anonymous --ftp-ssl --ftp-ssl-reqd --ftp-pasv --disable-epsv --key mykey.pem --cert mycert.crt -T helloworld.txt ftp://ftp.example.com:9876/upload/
```

(Word to the wise: use ftp:// in the URL, not ftps://)